# Grpc + roadrunner + mTLS + dynamic certificate renewal

Tags: grpc, mtls, roadrunner

Grpc can manage mTLS for secure tunnel communication. However, if the certificates renew, do I need to reload/restart roadrunner plugin?
Is it possible for roadrunner plugin to pick the new certificate dynamically with any need of reload/restart?

I have referred to roadrunner documentations, but nowhere I could see that new certificates would be kicked dynamically.
https://roadrunner.dev/docs/app-server-https/2.x/en

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you renew your certificates, you have to restart RR instance.
Here you can find new docs: [link](https://docs.roadrunner.dev/plugins/grpc)